# How to store grid checkbox value in array on button click

Tags: c#, gridview

I want to store datakey doc_id in array when it is checked using checkbox on button click event, already I've tried in list but i want in array. Help me out guys.

```cs
    protected void btnGetDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            List<string> getDoc = new List<string>();
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvApplDocs.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRow");
                {
                    if (ChkBoxRows.Checked == true)
                    {
                        getDoc.Add(gvApplDocs.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["doc_id"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Didn't actually understand what you want. But if you have list and want an array - then `list.ToArray()` should do the trick

Comment: I tried storing the doc_id in list when the checkBox click on button press. But I want to store it in string array format. Could you please reWork on my above code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert it to string[]?

```
protected void btnGetDocument_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  List<string> getDoc = new List<string>();
  foreach (GridViewRow row in gvApplDocs.Rows)
  {
    CheckBox ChkBoxRows = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRow");
    {
      if (ChkBoxRows.Checked == true)
      {
        getDoc.Add(gvApplDocs.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["doc_id"].ToString());
      }
    }
  }
  string[] getDocArray = getDoc.ToArray(); 
}
```

And don't forget

```
using System.Linq;
```